# OpenJPA + Tomcat JDBC Connection Pooling = stale data

Tags: mysql, tomcat, connection-pooling, openjpa, autocommit

I am using the Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool with OpenJPA in a web application. The application does not see updated data.  Specifically, another java application adds or removes records from the database, but the web application never sees these updates. This is quite a serious issue.  I must be missing something basic.

If I remove the Connection Pool from the implementation, the web application sees the updates.  It's as if the web application's commits are never called on the Connection.

Version info:

Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool:  org.apache.tomcat tomcat-jdbc 7.0.21

OpenJPA: org.apache.openjpa openjpa 2.0.1

Here is the code fragment that creates the DataSource (DataSourceHelper.findOrCreateDataSource method):

```
PoolConfiguration props = new PoolProperties();
props.setUrl(URL);
props.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);
props.setDriverClassName(dd.getClass().getName());
props.setUsername(username);
props.setPassword(pw);
props.setJdbcInterceptors("org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"+
              "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;"+
              "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReportJmx;"+
              "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer");   
props.setLogAbandoned(true);
props.setSuspectTimeout(120);
props.setJmxEnabled(true);
props.setInitialSize(2);
props.setMaxActive(100);
props.setTestOnBorrow(true);
if (URL.toUpperCase().contains(DB2)) {
    props.setValidationQuery("VALUES (1)");
} else if (URL.toUpperCase().contains(MYSQL)) {
    props.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    props.setConnectionProperties("relaxAutoCommit=true");
} else if (URL.toUpperCase().contains(ORACLE)) {
    props.setValidationQuery("select 1 from dual");
}
props.setValidationInterval(3000);
dataSource = new DataSource();
dataSource.setPoolProperties(props);
```

Here is the code that creates the EntityManagerFactory using the DataSource:

```
//props contains the connection url, user name, and password
DataSource dataSource = DataSourceHelper.findOrCreateDataSource("DATAMGT", URL, username, password);
props.put("openjpa.ConnectionFactory", dataSource);
emFactory = (OpenJPAEntityManagerFactory) Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DATAMGT", props);
```

If I comment out the DataSource like so, then it works.  Note that OpenJPA has enough information in the props to configure the connection without using the DataSource.

```
//props contains the connection url, user name, and password
//DataSource dataSource = DataSourceHelper.findOrCreateDataSource("DATAMGT", URL, username, password);
//props.put("openjpa.ConnectionFactory", dataSource);
emFactory = (OpenJPAEntityManagerFactory) Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("DATAMGT", props);
```

So somehow, the combination of OpenJPA and the Connection Pool is not working correctly.

UPDATE:

Actually, it seems to fail when the underlying database is MySQL.  It works correctly with and without the pool if the underlying database is DB2.

UPDATE #2:

I added a JdbcInterceptor to the pool to log the methods getting called on the connection.  When the database is DB2, setAutoCommit(true) is gets called when the EntityManager is created.  When the database is MySQL it is not getting called.

This would account for the difference in behavior. Even though the application is calling commit on the EntityManager, there is no corresponding commit on the Connection. Since all the queries executed during the transaction are read-only, OpenJPA seems to think a commit is not needed.

Here is the log from MySQL:

```
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: ******************Start JPA Properties:
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: *********openjpa.ConnectionDriverName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: *********openjpa.ConnectionPassword: *******
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: *********openjpa.ConnectionUserName: *******
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: *********openjpa.ConnectionURL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datamgt
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: *********openjpa.Log: log4j
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: ***** Found Driver :com.mysql.jdbc.Driver class: class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: ******************End JPA Properties:
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.em: ********EntityManagerFactory created
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.em: ******** Creating EntityManager
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****getAutoCommit Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection getMetaData Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection getMetaData Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection close Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.em: ********Entity manager created
```

Here is the log from DB2 (Note the setAutoCommit):

```
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: ******************Start JPA Properties:
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: *********openjpa.ConnectionDriverName: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: *********openjpa.ConnectionPassword: *******
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: *********openjpa.ConnectionUserName: *******
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: *********openjpa.ConnectionURL: jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/DATAMGT
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: *********openjpa.Log: log4j
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: ***** Found Driver :com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver class: class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
 INFO : .store.EMHandler.getConfig: ******************End JPA Properties:
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.em: ********EntityManagerFactory created
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.em: ******** Creating EntityManager
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****getAutoCommit Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****setAutoCommit Args: true 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection getMetaData Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection getMetaData Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection createStatement Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection getTransactionIsolation Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection close Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.em: ********Entity manager created
```

Since making this discovery, I have tried setting autoCommit to true like so, prior to creating the EntityManagerFactory:

```
dataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);
```

This has no effect.  I have read other posts on stackoverflow that OpenJPA sets autoCommit to false, and I have seen this in the logs, but only when committing a transaction that includes updates to the database.

I have lately been examining the transactionIsolationLevel and it turns out that MySQL has a default level of 4 whereas DB2 is 2.  Here is the definition of these from the java.sql.Connection class.  Note that 2 is even MORE relaxed than 4, so this is probably not the cause.

```
/**
 * A constant indicating that
 * dirty reads are prevented; non-repeatable reads and phantom
 * reads can occur.  This level only prohibits a transaction
 * from reading a row with uncommitted changes in it.
 */
int TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED   = 2;

/**
 * A constant indicating that
 * dirty reads and non-repeatable reads are prevented; phantom
 * reads can occur.  This level prohibits a transaction from
 * reading a row with uncommitted changes in it, and it also
 * prohibits the situation where one transaction reads a row,
 * a second transaction alters the row, and the first transaction
 * rereads the row, getting different values the second time
 * (a "non-repeatable read").
 */
int TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ  = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is there is a bug in OpenJPA.  The workaround is to call commit on the connection yourself.

Obtain the connection from the EntityManager, cast it to java.sql.Connection and call commit().

The bug is that OpenJPA  never calls commit on the connection for **read-only** transactions.  This would be fine if autoCommit were set to true, but OpenJPA insists on having autoCommit be false. When the EntityManager is created, if the underlying connection has autoCommit set to true, OpenJPA sets it false.

In the log fragment below, I get a connection from the DataSource before creating the EntityManager, and log the autoCommit and transactionIsolation.  During creation of the EntityManager, the log shows that autoCommit is then set to false.

```
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****getAutoCommit Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection getTransactionIsolation Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.em: Isolation level: 4 autoCommit: true
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection close Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.em: ********EntityManagerFactory created
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.em: ******** Creating EntityManager
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****getAutoCommit Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****setAutoCommit Args: false 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection getMetaData Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection getMetaData Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection close Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.em: ********Entity manager created
```

On the other hand, when the database is DB2, the opposite happens.  In the log fragment below, the autoCommit is NOT set to false.

```
DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****getAutoCommit Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection getTransactionIsolation Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.em: Isolation level: 2 autoCommit: true
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection close Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.em: ********EntityManagerFactory created
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.em: ******** Creating EntityManager
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****getAutoCommit Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection getMetaData Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection getMetaData Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection createStatement Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection getTransactionIsolation Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection close Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.em: ********Entity manager created
```

Furthermore, if the autoCommit setting starts out as false, OpenJPA sets it true for DB2, and leaves it alone for MySQL. I won't bother showing the logs for these cases.

For completeness, I will mention what I have observed during updates. For DB2, autoCommit is set to false, the updates are performed, commit is called on the connection, and autoCommit is set back to true.  Here is a log fragment for DB2:

```
DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.commitTransaction: >>>calling COMMIT transaction 544096693
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****getAutoCommit Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection getTransactionIsolation Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****getAutoCommit Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****setAutoCommit Args: false 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection isReadOnly Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection prepareStatement Args: INSERT INT 1003 1007 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection prepareStatement Args: INSERT INT 1003 1007 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection prepareStatement Args: INSERT INT 1003 1007 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection prepareStatement Args: UPDATE DAT 1003 1007 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection prepareStatement Args: UPDATE DAT 1003 1007 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****commit Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****setAutoCommit Args: true 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection close Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.commitTransaction: >>>finished COMMIT transaction 544096693
```

For MySQL, because autoCommit is already false, it is not changed during updates.  Here is the log anyway:

```
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.commitTransaction: >>>calling COMMIT transaction 2103121779
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****getAutoCommit Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****getAutoCommit Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection isReadOnly Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection prepareStatement Args: INSERT INT 1003 1007 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection prepareStatement Args: INSERT INT 1003 1007 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection prepareStatement Args: INSERT INT 1003 1007 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection prepareStatement Args: UPDATE DAT 1003 1007 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection prepareStatement Args: UPDATE DAT 1003 1007 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection !****commit Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.util.CommitInterceptor.invoke: Method called on connection close Args: 
 DEBUG: .store.impl.EMHandlerImpl.commitTransaction: >>>finished COMMIT transaction 2103121779
```

It's interesting that this bug only shows up when using Connection Pooling. I propose that this is because commit is never called on connections which are reused.  Without Connection Pooling, OpenJPA gets a fresh connection each time, and so all the updates that took place concurrently are found on the next query.

Answer (score 0):

Julie, 
I'm using tomcat 7 (with native pool) and openjpa 2.2. I have encountered an issue that JPA sometimes(!) brings the stale data after the page refresh.

When I have added

```
defaultAutoCommit="true"
```

in the connection pool configuration (server.xml), that did the trick.

> **defaultAutoCommit** - (boolean) The default auto-commit state of connections created by this pool. If not set, default is JDBC driver default (If not set then the setAutoCommit method will not be called.)